# Casting is not a pointer type when downcasting

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a base class:

```
class Base{
   public:
      Base();
      virtual ~Base();
      .....
}

class Derived2: public Base{
    public:
       Derived2();
       ...
}
```

and in my main, i tried to dynamic cast boost::shared_ptr from base to derived2:

```
  testFunction(boost:shared_ptr<Base> base){
     Derived2*  derived2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(base);
}
```

Comment: Standard library has `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, boost probably has something similar.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are using `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 1):

Boost has `dynamic_pointer_cast`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Derived2> derived2 = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived2>(base);
```

Comment: @Coolboy `shared_ptr<const Derived2>` is not the same as `const shared_ptr<Dervied2>`. Make them both `shared_ptr<const Derived2>` and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> > The operand of a dynamic_cast is not a pointer type
>
> how can i fix it?

By not using a non-pointer type as operand of `dynamic_cast`. In other words, by using a pointer type as the operand.

You can get a pointer from a shared pointer using `get` member function.

Be careful to not let this bare pointer leak to outside the scope of the function. You can trust on its validity only as long as the argument `base` points to the object. Also don't attempt to take ownership of that bare pointer, since its ownership is already shared.

---

P.S. `std::shared_ptr` has been in the standard library since C++11.

P.P.S. `dynamic_cast` is a code smell.

Comment: Just realized, yes.

Comment: While dynamic cast might be valid, with smart pointer's underlieing pointet it's outright error, the contonuity of reference counter is broken. dynamic_pointer_cast actually attempts to cast the smart pointer object and returns empty one if fails.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Dynamic cast isn't any more broken than any other call to `get`. You copy (or move) a shared pointer for later storage (in this case, through the use of `dynamic_pointer_cast`), or use `get` when you need the pointer only for the duration of a pre-existing shared pointer instance.

Comment: @eerorika if the original shared_pointer was last one, or when it becomes last one and destroyed, saved "dynamic_casted" pointer becomes invalid, so it cannot be saved for duration long enough for object to be destroyed. `dynamic_pointer_cast` supposed to use special constructor of `shared_pointer`, which is slightly different from copy one, which happens while function's argument still valid.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie And that is exactly why you must not let the bare pointer get out of the function, as I explain in the answer.